# Use Cloudfront URL for iFrame

Tags: express, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Nodejs - Express middleware that alters incoming file requests to point to Cloudfront

```
function cloudfrontController({url}, res, next) {
  const ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
  const name = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  const location = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
  const newurl = `${config.aws.cloudfront}${location}/${encodeURIComponent(name)}`;
  request(newurl).pipe(res);
}
```

I display the pdf in an iframe on the front end.
This seems to work fine when I use the S3 URL, however, the PDF does not load when using the the cloudfront URL. When I update the src of my frame with a new Cloudfront URL, the pdf downloads (but still doesn't display). In essence, this works but defeats the purpose of using cloudfront in the first place:

```
  const newurl = `${ext === 'pdf' ? config.aws.s3 : config.aws.cloudfront}${location}/${encodeURIComponent(name)}`;
```

Examples:

*S3 URL Works for iFrame*

https://npg-cloud.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/companies/ipadmin/users/57a8b211f77b5b3801255034/57a8b211f77b5b3801255034_1564598795092.pdf

*CloudFront URL doesn't work for iFrame*

https://d2eva5limbx0hv.cloudfront.net/companies/ipadmin/users/57a8b211f77b5b3801255034/57a8b211f77b5b3801255034_1564598795092.pdf

Comment: what error do you get ? Direct link works for me, check browser's console tab to see any error for iframe

Comment: Hi @JamesDean. There's no error. The frame is blank and the pdf downloads instead of appearing in the frame.